# WSDL service returning null for the nested object while consuming in .net, but returning correct value in Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I am consuming  third party WSDL service in .net. In the response of service call I am getting properties values correctly but there is one nested object of that response and it is always returning the null. I observed in Fiddler it is returning the correct xml even for nested object. Below is the XML which I am getting from fiddler and snap of object values.

[image: Response of object in .net returning null, but other properties are coming properly]

Below is the xml which I am getting from Fiddler response.

[image: Fiddler Response]

How we can resolve that?
Below is the proxy generated for transaccionPSERespuesta

```
  /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34281")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://ws.iatai.com/")]
public partial class transaccionPSERespuesta : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string idTransaccionField;

    private string referenciaField;

    private int idEstadoField;

    private string nombreEstadoField;

    private string codigoTrazabilidadField;

    private string codigoRespuestaField;

    private string codigoAutorizacionField;

    private float valorField;

    private float ivaField;

    private string isoMonedaField;

    private string fechaProcesamientoField;

    private string mensajeField;

    private string ipField;

    private bancoPSERespuesta bancoPSERespuestaField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string idTransaccion {
        get {
            return this.idTransaccionField;
        }
        set {
            this.idTransaccionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("idTransaccion");
        }
    }
```

Proxy generated for bancoPSERespuesta as follow:

```
 /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34281")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://ws.iatai.com/")]
public partial class bancoPSERespuesta : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string codigoField;

    private string nombreField;

    private string urlField;

    /// <remarks/>
```

Comment: The missing part seems to be skipped in deserialization, so there's probably a mismatch between the XML and the serialization attributes in the proxy classes. Please include (the relevant parts of) the proxy types `transaccionPSERespuesta` and `bancoPSERespuesta` in your question.

Comment: @nodots Added proxy generated code for transaccionPSERespuesta and bancoPSERespuesta.